# How to access DirectSound device info from Python?

Tags: python, directx, ctypes

I've found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525320/how-to-enumerate-audio-out-devices-in-c) information on SO about how to enumerate the sound device info on with .NET, but I don't really know how to use this information with Python.  As you can probably tell, I have almost zero experience with Windows API programming.

I can figure out how to get basic information via WMI, but I need more information, and it looks like maybe the following C# code snippet is what I need, but I just don't know how to access DirectSound objects from Python.  I've figured out some basic stuff with ctypes, but I don't know which or how to load the DirectX .dll...

```
DevicesCollection devColl = new DevicesCollection();
    foreach (DeviceInformation devInfo in devColl)
    {
        Device dev = new Device(devInfo.DriverGuid);   

        //use dev.Caps, devInfo to access a fair bit of info about the sound device
    }
```

Any pointers?

Comment: Which Python are you using? IronPython right?

Comment: I'm currently using CPython, but I could switch to IronPython with no problem if needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a "poor man's" .NET library access, take a look at ["Python for .NET"](http://pythonnet.sourceforge.net/).

However, it is potentially easier to access DirectSound devices with [IronPython](http://ironpython.codeplex.com/) due to its .NET bindings via its `clr` library.

Tips from [IronPython cookbook](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/Contents#Graphics_.26_Multimedia):

[Playing an MP3 song with DirectX](http://www.ironpython.info/index.php/How_To_Play_a_MP3):

```
import clr
clr.AddReference('Microsoft.DirectX.AudioVideoPlayback')
from Microsoft.DirectX import AudioVideoPlayback
mp3 = AudioVideoPlayback.Audio("C:\\myreallyfunky.mp3")
mp3.Play()
```

A more comprehensive tutorial of using Managed DirectX in IronPython can be found from http://www.neotitans.com/resources/dot-net/mdx-ironpython-1.html