# Detecting input and output audio devices separately in C#

Tags: c#

I am trying to search for all available sound input and outut devices and adding their names into a `ComboBox`.
I am using this code (found here at stackoverflow in a similiar question):

```
ManagementObjectSearcher mo = new ManagementObjectSearcher("select * from Win32_SoundDevice");

foreach (ManagementObject soundDevice in mo.Get())
{
    string deviceId = soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("DeviceId").ToString();
    string name = soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();

    comboBox1.Items.Add(name);
}
```

But this seems to select all available devices, I need to separate input devices and output devices. Is there a simple way of editing this code, or is there a more sophisticated method needed?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to enumerate audio out devices in c#](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525320/how-to-enumerate-audio-out-devices-in-c-sharp)

Comment: I found several related questions, but somehow I missed that one. It actually seems to solve my problem, thanks