# How to identify system audio device?

Tags: c#

I want to identify system audio device not default audio device. 
I have USB headset, Bluetooth headset connected to my system. Default audio device can be anything - system audio, Bluetooth or USB.

How to uniquely identify system audio device? Please help.

```
foreach (ManagementObject soundDevice in mo.Get())
{
    String deviceId = soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("DeviceId").ToString();
    String name = soundDevice.GetPropertyValue("Name").ToString();
}
```

Comment: you should try that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1525320/how-to-enumerate-audio-out-devices-in-c-sharp